# SQLite "LIKE" operator is very slow compared to the "=" operator

Tags: sql, performance, sqlite, database-performance, sqlperformance

When I am using the `LIKE` operator in SQLite, it is very slow compared to when I use the `=` instead.
It takes about 14ms with the `=` operator, but when I use `LIKE`, it takes about 440ms. I am testing this with `DB Browser for SQLite`. Here is the query that works fast:

```
SELECT re.ENTRY_ID, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(re.READING_ELEMENT, '§') AS read_element,
       GROUP_CONCAT(re.FURIGANA_BOTTOM, '§') AS furigana_bottom,
       GROUP_CONCAT(re.FURIGANA_TOP, '§') AS furigana_top,
       GROUP_CONCAT(re.NO_KANJI, '§') AS no_kanji,
       GROUP_CONCAT(re.READING_COMMONNESS, '§') AS read_commonness, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(re.READING_RELATION, '§') AS read_rel,
       GROUP_CONCAT(se.SENSE_ID, '§') AS sense_id, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(se.GLOSS, '§') AS gloss, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(se.POS, '§') AS pos, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(se.FIELD, '§') AS field,
       GROUP_CONCAT(se.DIALECT, '§') AS dialect, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(se.INFORMATION, '§') AS info 
FROM Jmdict_Reading_Element AS re LEFT JOIN 
     Jmdict_Sense_Element AS
     se ON re.ENTRY_ID = se.ENTRY_ID
WHERE re.ENTRY_ID IN (SELECT ENTRY_ID FROM Jmdict_Reading_Element WHERE READING_ELEMENT = 'example') OR 
      re.ENTRY_ID IN (SELECT ENTRY_ID FROM Jmdict_Sense_Element WHERE GLOSS = 'example')
 GROUP BY re.ENTRY_ID
```

The slows down when I change

```
WHERE re.ENTRY_ID IN (SELECT ENTRY_ID FROM Jmdict_Reading_Element WHERE READING_ELEMENT = 'example') OR 
re.ENTRY_ID IN (SELECT ENTRY_ID FROM Jmdict_Sense_Element WHERE GLOSS = 'example')
```

to

```
WHERE re.ENTRY_ID IN (SELECT ENTRY_ID FROM Jmdict_Reading_Element WHERE READING_ELEMENT LIKE 'example') OR 
re.ENTRY_ID IN (SELECT ENTRY_ID FROM Jmdict_Sense_Element WHERE GLOSS LIKE 'example')
```

I need to do this so that I can use wildcards e.g.

```
WHERE re.ENTRY_ID IN (SELECT ENTRY_ID FROM Jmdict_Reading_Element WHERE READING_ELEMENT LIKE 'example%') OR 
re.ENTRY_ID IN (SELECT ENTRY_ID FROM Jmdict_Sense_Element WHERE GLOSS LIKE 'example%')
```

Here is a link to the database itself:
https://www.mediafire.com/file/hyuymc84022gzq7/dictionary.db/file

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[FTS?](http://%20%20%20%20create%20virtual%20table%20jre_fts%20using%20FTS4(entry_id,reading_element);%20%20%20%20%20insert%20into%20jre_fts%20select%20entry_id,%20reading_element%20from%20Jmdict_Reading_Element;%20%20%20%20%20create%20virtual%20table%20jse_fts%20using%20FTS4(entry_id,gloss);%20%20%20%20%20insert%20into%20jse_fts%20select%20entry_id,%20gloss%20from%20Jmdict_Sense_Element;)

Using DB Browser for sqlite on Win 10.

- "fast" query returns 25 rows in 84ms
- "slow" query (using `LIKE "example%"`) returns 33 rows in 1025ms

Created fts4 tables like so:

```
create virtual table jre_fts using FTS4(entry_id,reading_element);
insert into jre_fts select entry_id, reading_element from Jmdict_Reading_Element;
create virtual table jse_fts using FTS4(entry_id,gloss);
insert into jse_fts select entry_id, gloss from Jmdict_Sense_Element;
```

It took 7390ms, database grew from 70,296KB to 110,708KB.

Modified the WHERE like so:

```
 WHERE re.ENTRY_ID IN (SELECT ENTRY_ID FROM jre_fts WHERE READING_ELEMENT MATCH '^example') OR 
re.ENTRY_ID IN (SELECT ENTRY_ID FROM jse_fts WHERE GLOSS MATCH '^example')
```

Query returned 33 rows in 60ms.

I cannot test or analyze how FTS will work on the `reading_element` column, but perhapse the approach shows promise.

Answer (score 3):

Try putting a full-text index on the columns you are using.

see [Full Text Indexing](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/learn-sql-server/understanding-full-text-indexing-in-sql-server/)

**Create Catalog**

```
USE {yourDB}  
GO  
CREATE FULLTEXT CATALOG {catalogName}
WITH ACCENT_SENSITIVITY = OFF
```

**Create Index**

```
USE {yourDB}  
GO  
CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX ON {someTable} ({col1}, {col2})
ON catalogName
```

**Note**
This is more of a convenience, but see if your collation is case insensitive so that for example an 'a' = 'A'. Normally the collation will have a ci_utf8 for example (ci = case insensitive). I do this for the user and programmer convenience.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if using `HAVING` would speed your query:

```
SELECT re.ENTRY_ID, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(re.READING_ELEMENT, '§') AS read_element,
       GROUP_CONCAT(re.FURIGANA_BOTTOM, '§') AS furigana_bottom,
       GROUP_CONCAT(re.FURIGANA_TOP, '§') AS furigana_top,
       GROUP_CONCAT(re.NO_KANJI, '§') AS no_kanji,
       GROUP_CONCAT(re.READING_COMMONNESS, '§') AS read_commonness, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(re.READING_RELATION, '§') AS read_rel,
       GROUP_CONCAT(se.SENSE_ID, '§') AS sense_id, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(se.GLOSS, '§') AS gloss, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(se.POS, '§') AS pos, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(se.FIELD, '§') AS field,
       GROUP_CONCAT(se.DIALECT, '§') AS dialect, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(se.INFORMATION, '§') AS info 
FROM Jmdict_Reading_Element re LEFT JOIN 
     Jmdict_Sense_Element se
     ON re.ENTRY_ID = se.ENTRY_ID
GROUP BY re.ENTRY_ID
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN re.READING_ELEMENT = 'example' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0 OR
       SUM(CASE WHEN se.GLOSS = 'example' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0);
```

Comment: That didn't speed it up :(

Comment: @AdenDiamond . . . Of course not.  I needed to remove the `WHERE` clause.  Try this version.